# Mongoose select only fields explicitly declared in Schema

Tags: mongoose

When using Mongoose and querying the DB, by default all fields are selected, and I have to explicitly tell Mongoose which fields I do not want to select, for instance if I do not want the field `user` I should do:

```
var schema = new Schema(
    {
    insertedAt: {type: String},
    tags: {type: String},
    user: {type:Object, select:false},
    connectedIds: {type:Array}
    }
```

The problem is, fields might be added to the db without the API developer (me) knowing about it.

Is it possible to tell Mongoose to *only* select fields that are explicitly set?

Comment: The default query of mongo, adds a field, 'projection' that does exactlly this job. Is it not possible to set the projection from the schema with mongoose? Documentation of the schema might help. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-select

Answer (score 6):

There's a workaround to always select only fields defined in your `Schema`. What you have to do is to get all fields with the schema `paths` property and pass it to your `select()` statement, like:

```
var fields = Object.keys(yourSchema.paths).join(' ');

//and when execute a query
YourModel.find({}).select(fields).exec(callback);
```

That way, even if someone add a new field to your objects, it'll never be shown. The disadvantage is that you have to do that for every query.