# Mongoose does not validate schemas on queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose

Mongoose seems to force schema validation only when writing on the database, not when querying it. More specifically, attributes not defined in the `Schema` are still returned by queries.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
// MongoDB collection "test.objs" is filled with one object: { a: 1 }
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test");     
schema = new mongoose.Schema({ b: Number });
model = mongoose.model("obj",schema);
// Prints {}, as expected
console.log(new model({ a: 1 }));
// Prints { a: 1 } but I expect {}
model.find(function(e,val){ console.log(val[0]) });
model.find(function(e,val){ console.log(val[0].toObject({ strict: true })); });
```

How to do schema validation on read queries?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28074472/2241993) helps you.

Comment: The problem is not about the projection/selection of fields but about their validation. It should not even be possible to select/view the attribute `a` considering it is not in the schema.

Comment: Mongoose doesn't validate if the objects in a certain `mongodb` collection have the same keys defined in the respective collection `Schema`. When running a query, it'll return the docs that match the query criteria, the way they're persisted. If you want to filter which fields must be shown, you have to specify it. That's why I linked the answer.