# Mongoose - Exclude the fields that are in DB and not in Mongoose Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

We are creating a NodeJS API using Express Framework with backend datastore as Mongo DB. We are using Mongoose package for interacting with the Mongo Database. The Mongoose Schema is as below:

```
const user = new Schema(
{
    id: { type: String, immutable: true },      
    firstName: { type: String, maxlength: 100 },
    lastName: { type: String, maxlength: 100 },
    email: { type: String, maxlength: 500 },        
},
{
    timestamps: true,
    strict: true
});
```

We have used the `strict: false` so that fields that are not defined in the schema are not getting saved to Mongo. We also need to ensure that if there are some extra field in the User Document in the Mongo Database, that will not be exposed as part of the User Get. We could see that `find()` operation accepts are option to select the field that needs to be excluded. Is there a way other than that to make the API responses inline with the Mongoose Schema defined above?

Comment: Are you saying you can prove that `await user.findOne()`  returns more than fields defined in your schema?

Comment: @AlexBlex - Yes. say if we have phone number field in the database, the find or findone or findbyid methods return all the data and that is going out in the API

Comment: Would https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28063849/mongoose-select-only-fields-explicitly-declared-in-schema answer your question?