# Mongoose doesn't throw errors when schema does not match documents in my database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, next.js13

First time working with NextJS and Mongoose and there's something I don't understand. Here's an example of a document in my database:

```
{
  youtube: {
    link: 'https://youtubelinkhere',
    start: '00:00:10',
    end: '00:01:30'
  },
  _id: new ObjectId('AAA'),
  targetMuscle: 'calf',
}
```

Note **targetMuscle** property. And here's the schema file:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

export interface IExercise extends mongoose.Document {
    muscle: string;
    youtube: {
        link: string;
        start: string;
        end: string;
    };
}

const exercisesSchema = new mongoose.Schema<IExercise>({
    muscle: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    youtube: {
        link: { type: String, required: true },
        start: { type: String, required: false },
        end: { type: String, required: false }
    }
});

export default mongoose.models.exercise || mongoose.model<IExercise>('exercise', exercisesSchema);
```

**Note the "muscle" property** For some reason, when I try to get a muscle document like this:

```
const exercises = await Exercises.findOne({targetMuscle: targetMuscle});
```

It works, even though I think it shouldn't. In fact, my application works even when my schema file contents are like this:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

export interface IExercise extends mongoose.Document {
}

const exercisesSchema = new mongoose.Schema<IExercise>({
});

export default mongoose.models.exercise || mongoose.model<IExercise>('exercise', exercisesSchema);
```

It seems it works as long as I'm exporting something. Even when I get rid of the `mongoose.models.exercise` part of the export statement my query still works. Is there something about Schemas I'm not understanding? If I delete the schema file or don't have an export, the query doesn't work though.

This brings me to my second question. Will it be a pain to do migrations with Mongoose? My query will probably need to evolve over time, should I switch to Prisma?

Answer (score 1):

You've described the way mongoose works with Mongo.  If you have strict mode enabled (it is by default), object fields not defined in your schema won't get written to the database. As long as you only ever update the mongo collection through mongoose, you'll never have any extraneous fields on your documents.

But if another process modifies the documents in the collection, you well might.

Someone posted a work-around here that ensures that only fields in your model are returned from queries here:

[Mongoose select only fields explicitly declared in Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28063849/mongoose-select-only-fields-explicitly-declared-in-schema)

where you basically explicitly pass all the paths of your model into the query:

```
const fields = Object.keys(yourSchema.paths).join(' ');

//and when execute a query
YourModel.find({}).select(fields).exec(callback);
```

But needing to do this sort of sanitization strikes me as a code smell.  If there's something unacceptable about the way mongo/ose works, maybe it's the wrong tool for the job.